# Tracking packet processing delay on a single host using perf?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel

I am crawling down the rabbit hole that is linux tracing. I am relatively new to perf and its abilities, but I think it can meet my demands, but I am unsure how to proceed in my work. I need a little guidance.

I want to measure packet processing latency of a single node (whether that is a container or a host), I think this is known also network propagation delay. I understand how basic network delay works, and I have used Ping for (RTT) and iPerf3 to track and plot some simple statistics. Although this may give us a view of the entire network as a whole, it doesn't really tell us much about latency caused by the linux network stack.

Now I want to consider measuring packet processing latency of the linux kernel stack. With my current knowledge, I know we can track 'net:*' events, such as when the packet first enters, it will trigger the 'netif_rx'. This should be the starting time of a packet entering the nic to be processed by the linux kernel.

For example, running `perf trace --no-syscalls --event 'net:*' ping 172.19.0.4 -c1 > /dev/null` results in

```
0.000 ping/811 net:net_dev_queue(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 98, name: "eth0")
0.049 ping/811 net:net_dev_start_xmit(name: "eth0", skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, protocol: 2048, len: 98, network_offset: 14, transport_offset_valid: 1, transport_offset: 34)
0.077 ping/811 net:netif_rx_entry(name: "veth1c585f6", napi_id: 3, skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, protocol: 2048, len: 84, truesize: 768, mac_header_valid: 1, mac_header: 4294967282)
0.102 ping/811 net:netif_rx(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 84, name: "veth1c585f6")
0.143 ping/811 net:netif_rx_exit(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 84, name: "veth1c585f6")
0.169 ping/811 net:net_dev_xmit(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 98, name: "eth0")
0.186 ping/811 net:netif_receive_skb(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 84, name: "veth1c585f6")
0.224 ping/811 net:netif_receive_skb_entry(name: "br-e26d82c11b7e", napi_id: 3, skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, protocol: 2048, ip_summed: 2, len: 84, truesize: 768, mac_header_valid: 1, mac_header: 4294967282)
0.240 ping/811 net:netif_receive_skb(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 84, name: "br-e26d82c11b7e")
0.271 ping/811 net:netif_receive_skb_exit(skbaddr: 0xffff8d110b2a4600, len: 84, name: "br-e26d82c11b7e")
```

Here I am pinging another docker container (on the same host for now). I relatively understand what these steps are doing.

- `net:net_dev_queue`: The network device queue received a new packet (skbaddr) of size len on the Ethernet interface named eth0.
- `net:net_dev_start_xmit`: The Ethernet driver started transmitting a packet (skbaddr) of size len on the interface named eth0, using protocol number protocol.
- `net:netif_rx_entry`: The network interface veth1c585f6 received a packet (skbaddr) of size len and protocol protocol, and is now processing it.
- `net:netif_rx`: The network interface veth1c585f6 received a packet (skbaddr) of size len.
- `net:netif_rx_exit`: The packet received by veth1c585f6 has been fully processed and is now ready to be passed up the stack.
- `net:net_dev_xmit`: The kernel is about to transmit a packet (skbaddr) of size len on the interface named eth0.
- `net:netif_receive_skb`: A packet (skbaddr) of size len was received on the interface named veth1c585f6.
- `net:netif_receive_skb_entry`: The bridge br-e26d82c11b7e received a packet (skbaddr) of size len and protocol protocol, and is now processing it (using NAPI id 3).
- `net:netif_receive_skb`: The bridge br-e26d82c11b7e received a packet (skbaddr) of size len.
- `net:netif_receive_skb_exit`: The packet received by br-e26d82c11b7e has been fully processed and is now ready to be delivered.

I did some linux kernel reading to do this.

Thus. Here is my question. How would I use this tracepoint method to calculate packet processing latency (and therefore jitter). Could I use perf to do such measurements over large packet flows (sending packets from one container to another container).

A thought process: I am also aware of the tracepoint `syscalls:sys_exit_execve()` , a tracepoint function  that is triggered when the `execve()` system call returns after executing a new program. Thus, this should be the "last" tracepoint call before a packet when dealing with a packet. Finding the difference between these two time would equal a rough estimate?

Thanks!